# Save and error callback on Angular $Resource

Tags: angularjs

This is a basic angular web application with a html view and a model angular controller class

My angular controller script file contains

```
 var taskResource = $resource("http://localhost:3000/api/tasks/:id", { id: '@id' });

 $scope.tasks = taskResource.query();

  noError =  function() {
        $scope.error = "";

    }

    onFailure = function () {
        $scope.error = "Error communicating with server";
    }

 $scope.changeTaskDone = function (task) {
        $scope.tasks.$save(task, noError, onFailure);

        };
```

My html contains

```
 <tr ng-class="{'task-done': task.done}" ng-repeat="task in tasks | orderBy: '-priority'">
                        <td class="small-cell">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ng-click="deleteTask(task)">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td class="small-cell">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.done" ng-change="changeTaskDone(task)" />
                        </td>
```

The noError and OnFailure callbacks are not being called.

EDIT
localhost is a node server developed by me. What should I send from the node server in order for the success callback to get activated in the client side.
Now its only sending a res.status(200);

Comment: Are the methods not found or not being called? Do you get any error message?

Comment: The methods are not being called. I use visual studio . Had put the debug point on onError and onFailure and they are not being hit

Comment: when I stop the localhost server, the OnFailure is called. So the error callback is working. But the success callback NoError is not .

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the reference instantiated by $resource, ex:

```
$scope.changeTaskDone = function (task) {
    taskResource.save(task, noError, onFailure);
};
```

Comment: taskResource.save(task, noError, onFailure);
the onerror callback OnFailure is working when localhost is shut down. but the success callback is not when localhost is running.

Comment: Can you exemplify?

Comment: the error was not in the client side but on the server side. I was also programming in node and express at the client side

Answer (score 0):

In node server, I was not using res.send() along res.status(200);